# Transition for Gradient Background

Tags: css, hover, transition, gradient, linear-gradients

In this (scss) code I have an element with Gradient bg and I set transition for it but it's not working when the gradient is changing.

```
.bg-gradient {
    background: $color_prime;
    background: linear-gradient(137deg, rgba($color_prime, 1) 57%, rgba($color_prime_lighter, 1) 100%);
    transition: all 25ms ease-in;

    &:hover {
        background: linear-gradient(137deg, rgba($color_prime, 1) 100%, rgba($color_prime_lighter, 1) 100%);
    }
}
```

Now I want when the user hovers on the element, its gradient bg being changed to another gradient bg with transition.